# Newtonsoft's JObject: read any property using a string expression

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JObject and want to get any property or array element coming from a string expression.

I already know how to do it explicitly, like:
`jObject["a"][0]["b");`

But I would like to do something like: `jObject("a[0].b");`

The reason is that I am allowing the user to specify what to gather from the JSON object, rather than hardcoding the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*SelectToken*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm#SelectTokenJSONPath)

```
string json = @"{a:[{b:1}]}";
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = jobj.SelectToken("a[0].b");
Console.WriteLine(token);
```